# Can I change the mouse pointer color?

Tags: mouse, vnc, window-manager, vim, colors

I'm faced with a small but long-time nuisance.
I frequently work remote from home using google remote desktop. I connect to my windows 10 PC and there I use vnc client to connect to my ubuntu 20.04 machines. And I use 'terminator' windows. Now because I use white characters on black background, the mouse pointer isn't so visible. So I right click at the terminal and select preferences - profiles -colors and change the 'Forground and Background' to 'Gruvbox Light' and I can see my mouse pointer, chacters ok. But using vim, when I press 'g followed by ctrl+]' for a symbol to list up the candidates for the symbol definition, there are some characters I can't see clearly because they use very close colors with yellow the background like bright sky blue. I can change the 'cursor' color but I wish I could change just the mouse pointer so that I can use the 'white characters on black background' and don't have that ctags list problem. How can I do that?

Comment: Which pointer do you want changed?  The Windows mouse color you do from the Control Panel or Settings under the Mouse Pointer Settings.  For Ubuntu it is probably under the Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad in the Themes tab, depending on your desktop flavor.  VNC does not use the host OS mouse theme to the remote system.

Comment: I see in the Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad, no Themes tab. I my guess is as you said, the VNC doesn't show the host OS's mouse theme..(?)

Comment: No, the mouse is generated by the OS and not by the host OS, so in Windows you would need to change it under Mouse Pointer settings.  Click on your Start menu button in Windows then just start typing Mouse Pointer and it should take you to those settings.

Comment: @Terrance But mouse pointer shape changes when I place the pointer on the terminal on VNC. I'm doing something else now so I'll try it sooner.

Comment: Yep, the mouse pointer usually becomes an I beam when in the terminal window.  You will need to choose a different theme for it in the Ubuntu part of it.  What desktop environment are you running?

Comment: I think it's GNOME. (from the apperance https://linuxconfig.org/the-8-best-ubuntu-desktop-environments-20-04-focal-fossa-linux)

Comment: Under the GNOME Tweaks, under Appearance and then Cursor is where you change the pointer theme.  You are going to have to choose one that will suit your needs or go to https://www.gnome-look.org/browse?cat=107&ord=latest and find a nice cursor theme that will help you out.  Beyond this if nothing looks good to you I am thinking that you might have to create your own theme for your mouse pointer to look the way you want it too.

Comment: @Terrance Yes, correct, I seleted 'Redglass' and the mouse pointer is bigger and red! I think this can be useful when I'm working from home. If your post an answer with your comments, I'll select it. (and it'll be useful for others.)

Comment: @Rinzwind should undelete the answer that he wrote since it is the same thing I told you for the last comment.