# Can I change the character colors that is used in ctags candidate listing?

Tags: themes, colors, terminator

When I use a certain theme in my 'terminator' setting, the tag candidate list uses colors that I don't want so I can't see them clearly when I'm working remotely. The figure is like this.
[image]
How can I change those colors? I don't like the pink and light blue colors. (From the window that pops up when I click right mouse button at the terminal background, I've selected in preferences-profile-colors -'Forground and Background', built-in scheme 'Gruvbox light').

Comment: You are asking the same question twice. They both ask the same thing how to change some colors. Please edit the first question and add this info to it. A second question that is almost identical is not a good idea.

Comment: @David the other question was materially different though - do you know if Tweaks can fix this problem as well as the original question asked by the OP [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1434881/can-i-change-the-mouse-pointer-color)? Its not a dupe.

Comment: You might need to change the Palette Colors to your liking.  Maybe something like Xterm to help the readability.